Problem with Image uploading website reloading
the problem is that I'm trying to pass an image file in a formdata object to my server, but as a result of this; the webpage keeps reloading. I've tried using preventdefault but it doesn't work in an onchange event.
Here is my HTML:
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/image_uploader.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/devchallenges.png">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.0.0-alpha.1/axios.min.js"></script>
    <title>Image-Uploader</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="box">
            <span id="upload"> Upload your image </span><br>
             <span id="file">File should be jpeg, png...</span> <br>
             <div id="overlay"></div>
             <span id="drag">
                 <span id="drag2">
                     <img src="img/image.svg" alt="image icon">
                     Drag & Drop your image here</span>
             </span> <br>
             <span id="or">Or</span>
                <form action="" id="form">
                    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="filed" onload="loadfile()" style="display: none;" >
                </form>
             <label id="choose" for="filed">Choose a file</label>
             <div id="input"></div>
             <button id="label" type="submit" for="input">Copy</button>
         </div>
         <div class="message">
            Image uploaded successfully.
            <button onclick="func1()" class="okay">Okay</button>
         </div>
        <!-- Progress bar -->
<div id="prog">
    <label id="prog-label" for="progress-bar">0%</label>
    <progress id="progress-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
         <footer> Philip Joe Yakubu</footer>
    </div>


const dropArea = document.querySelector("#drag");
const dragText = document.querySelector("#drag2");
const hide = document.getElementById("prog")
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
const message = document.querySelector(".message");
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const bar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
let button = document.querySelector("#choose");
let input = document.querySelector("#filed");
var copyButton = document.querySelector("#label");
var inp = document.getElementById("input");
let file;

input.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hide.style.display = "flex";
  file = input.files[0];
  dropArea.classList.add("active");
  console.log("successful1")
  console.log("it's successful");
  inp.innerHTML = " " + URL.createObjectURL(file) + " ";
  console.log("no problem so far")
  console.log(URL.createObjectURL(file))
  document.getElementById("label").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var copyText = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)
      .then(function() {
        alert("Text copied to clipboard: " + copyText);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        alert("Failed to copy text: " + error);
      });
  });

  // Create a new FormData instance
  var formData = new FormData();

  // Append the file to the FormData
  formData.append("image", file);

// Axios
const config = {
  onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
    progressEvent.preventDefault();
    const percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)*100);
   
      bar.setAttribute('value', percentCompleted);
      bar.previousElementSibling.textContent = `${percentCompleted}%`
      if (percentCompleted === 100) {
         setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("prog").style.display = "none";
        displayFile();
        overlay.style.display = 'block';
        message.style.display = "grid"
      }, 100);
      inp.style.display = "flex";
      copyButton.style.display = "flex";
      }
       // adjust the delay time as needed
  }
}

console.log(file);

axios.post('http://localhost:7777/upload', formData, config)
  .then(res => {
    console.log("Upload successful:", res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(file);
    console.error("Error uploading image:", err);
});

});


I tried passing the file in the input as a constant itself
const file = input.files[0];

axios.post('http://localhost:7777/upload', file, config)
  .then(res => {
    console.log("Upload successful:", res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(file);
    console.error("Error uploading image:", err);
});

but it seems my axios HTTPrequest will only accept multipart/formdata requests.

This question is similar to: How do I make an HTML button not reload the page. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
